# Логическая ошибка в python

Tags: python

Подбрасывает условную монету 100 раз. Считает сколько раз выпал орел (front), сколько решка (back).

Проблема в том, что при успешном завершении одного цикла, переменная `random` не меняется. Что делать?

```
import random
throw = 0
front = 0
back = 0

random = random.randint(1, 2)

while throw != 100: 
  if random == 1:
    front += 1
  elif random == 2:
    back += 1
  throw += 1

print(back)
print(front)
print(throw)
input("\n\nНажмите Enter, чтобы выйти")
```

Comment: Вы имя импортируемого модуля `random` отдали переменной, в которую записали значение `random.randint(1, 2)`. Поэтому, даже внеся выражение `random = random.randint(1, 2)` в тело цикла, вы получаете ошибку. Ведь у объекта типа `int` (который вернет `random.randint(1, 2)`) нет метода `randint`. Придумайте другое имя для переменной (вместо `random`, например, `var`) и внесите выражение `var = random.randint(1, 2)` в тело цикла.

Answer (score 4):

```
import random

throw = 100
front = list(random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(throw)).count(1)
back = throw - front

print(front, back)
```

51 49

Answer (score 1):

Получение результата `random.randint` нужно внести в цикл...

Comment: каким образом? Я пытался до блока if, после блока if, и.т.д. Компилятор ругается.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, следует сделать вызов функции random.randint(1, 2) внутри цикла тоже:

```
import random
throw = 0
front = 0
back = 0
while throw != 100:
    if random.randint(1, 2) == 1:
        front += 1
    else:
        back += 1
    throw += 1
print(back)
print(front)
print(throw)
input("\n\nНажмите Enter, чтобы выйти")
```

Comment: этот код я сам пробовал, но он почему-то не работает. Ваш тоже.